# Silverlight Gadget, Save data on client machine

Tags: silverlight, windows-desktop-gadgets

i have a Silverlight base desktop gadget. it was function well but want to save settings of gadget and updated info in to Xml and save on client Machine. **is that a possible or not** other way is to save on Server and map with machine name , but it will required service, is it better if i can store some data on client machine

Please Suggest me some way to do

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When an application stores data in a file, the file name and storage location must be carefully chosen to minimize the possibility that the storage location will be known to another application and, therefore, will be vulnerable to corruption. Without a standard system in place to manage these problems, developing ad hoc techniques that minimize storage conflicts can be complex, and the results can be unreliable.

With isolated storage, data is always isolated by user and by assembly. Credentials such as the origin or the strong name of the assembly determine assembly identity. Data can also be isolated by application domain, using similar credentials.

When you use isolated storage, your application saves data to a unique data compartment that is associated with some aspect of the code's identity, such as its publisher or signature. The data compartment is an abstraction, not a specific storage location; it consists of one or more isolated storage files, called stores, which contain the actual directory locations where data is stored. For example, an application might have a data compartment associated with it, and a directory in the file system would implement the store that actually preserves the data for that application. The data saved in the store can be any kind of data, from user preference information to application state. For the developer, the location of the data compartment is transparent. Stores usually reside on the client, but a server application could use isolated stores to store information by impersonating the user on whose behalf it is functioning. Isolated storage can also store information on a server with a user's roaming profile so that the information will travel with the roaming user.